# Mathmatically adding arrays in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, excel, powershell

I have two arrays that I need to add together (along with later subtract and multiply). The first is labeled $agrp and it contains data that is being pulled from a range in an excel sheet. I also have $bgrp that is pulling another range from the same excel sheet. I would like to add them together mathematically. So far, all I can do is get them to combine into a new array (now double the size). Any suggestions?

Comment: I want to get it into a value called $egrp. I have done $agrp + $bgrp which adds them both together. I have also tried a for loop with count. The issue with count is it just counts the amount of elements within the array (in this case 42). However, each element is unique (counts 1,2,3,4 for $agrp), and thus throws the error -- "You cannot index into a 2 dimensional array with index [ # ] " with the number being the element it failed on.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but why not leverage a program designed to do this, like, say, Excel? Why extract things into PowerShell just so it can do things it wasn't designed for?

Comment: I've done it in excel already, but now have to repeat the process in powershell. It's stupidly repetitive but its for a cs class taught by a non-cs teacher, hence why I'm so stuck. But, if I cant figure out the code I may just go back into a new excel workbook and use the built in functions and then re-extract that data. Thanks for the help mate, I wouldn't have thought of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to treat your arrays independently, you can use this:

```
$egrp = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

for ($i=0; $i -lt $agrp.Count; $i++){
    $egrp += $agrp[$i] + $bgrp[$i]
}
```

Although I don't like it because it's not very "powershell". So here's what I suggest if you need it to be extracted directly from the csv:

```
$egrp = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

Import-Csv $csv_path | 
%{[int]$_.agrp + [int]$_.bgrp} | 
%{$egrp += $_}
```

Note that the `$_.agrp` and `$_.bgrp` represent the names of the columns of the csv (in the first line). The `$csv_path` is the string path or file object of the csv.